# SSIS - How to pass datetime variable to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I wanted to create package in **SSIS**.

At one of the first steps I would like to set the 'bookmark' variable (data type in SQL is `datetime`) using SQL Server stored procedure. Than I would like to pass that variable to other stored procedure which would prepare the table to the export.

Unfortunately I got stuck with the issue which I guess is related to datatypes in SSIS, could you please have a look?

So I created an variable `time` for that:

[image: variable definition]

Than I used execute SQL task which have as SQL Statement:
`exec  MyProcedure ?,?,? out`

And Parameter mapping as per below:
[image: parameter mapping]

During the execution I can see that it is assigned as an expected (the only thing which is odd at that place is that SSIS uses `MM/DD/YYYY` format, while I have everywhere `YYYY/MM/DD`)
[image: value]

After that I have the SQL task which is calling the 2nd procedure:

`exec MyProcedure2 @var1 = ?, @var2 = ?, @bookmark =?`

[image]

And that component is failing all the time with the errors as per below:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "exec MyProcedure2
> @var1 = ?, @var2 = ?, ..." failed with the following error: "The type
> is not supported.DBTYPE_DBTIME". Possible failure reasons: Problems
> with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not
> set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Please note that the procedure runs without any issues when I trigger that directly from SQL with the same values.

My understanding/guess is that I messed up something with data types in SSIS... but I was trying change `DBTIME` to `DBTIME2`, `DBTIMESTAMP`, `DBDATE`, `DATE`.. and each time I was getting similar error messages and at this moment I am out of ideas.

Comment: You're trying to pass a datetime value to a dbtime. A datetime contains *both* a date and time (as the name suggests) but a dbtime, just a time (again, like the name suggests). SSIS doesn't have a time data type, so use a string type and ensure the value is in the format `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: According to this, the correct SSIS data type for `datetime` is `DBTIMESTAMP` https://wiki.melissadata.com/index.php?title=FAQ:SSIS:Data_Type_Conversions please try again with that and post the error message

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an OLEDB connection, I think User::time must be type NVARCHAR because it's an input variable.  I think it's different for output variables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-ver15#use-date-and-time-parameters-with-ole-db-connection-managers